# Chart.js line chart set background color

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm working with Chart.js and want to convert a line chart to a PNG. The problem is that the image always downloads with a transparent background, which is not what I need. I tried many options, nothing really worked.

And suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's one way to get a fully-opaque version of your ChartJS:**

Wait until the chart is fully animated out and complete. You can do this by adding the `onAnimationComplete` property to the chart.

In the `onAnimationComplete` function:

- Create an in-memory temporary canvas of equal size as your chart.
- Fill the temp canvas with white
- `drawImage` the ChartJS canvas over the white-filled temp canvas
- Create an image from the temp canvas.

**Here's how that might be done:**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
  responsive: true,
  onAnimationComplete:function(){
      var tcanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
      var tctx=tcanvas.getContext('2d');
      tcanvas.width=ctx.canvas.width;
      tcanvas.height=ctx.canvas.height;
      tctx.fillStyle='white';
      tctx.fillRect(0,0,tcanvas.width,tcanvas.height);
      tctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
      var img=new Image();
      img.onload=function(){
          document.body.appendChild(img);
      }
      img.src=tcanvas.toDataURL();
  }
});
```

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

var randomColorFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*255)};

var lineChartData = {
  labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
  datasets : [
    {
      label: "My First dataset",
      fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
      strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
      pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
    },
    {
      label: "My Second dataset",
      fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
      strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
      pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
    }
  ]

}

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
  responsive: true,
  onAnimationComplete:function(){
    var tcanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
    var tctx=tcanvas.getContext('2d');
    tcanvas.width=ctx.canvas.width;
    tcanvas.height=ctx.canvas.height;
    tctx.fillStyle='white';
    tctx.fillRect(0,0,tcanvas.width,tcanvas.height);
    tctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
    img.src=tcanvas.toDataURL();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<h4>ChartJS line chart</h4>
<div style="width:30%">
  <div>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<h4>Fully opaque chart as image</h4>
```

Answer (score 17):

Here's a solution that works perfectly, also when saving to an image file (like png). I'm blatantly copying this from @etimberg at the [chartjs issue tracker](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2830).

```
Chart.plugins.register({
  beforeDraw: function(chartInstance) {
    var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chartInstance.chart.width, chartInstance.chart.height);
  }
});
```

This should go *before* your chart in the source.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @Mark, This solution definitely works. But if you add a console.log statement in your beforeDraw function, I expect you will see, as I did, that it is getting called many times. Perhaps before every datapoint is drawn. That bothered me. So I kept searching and pieced together a solution for "underfilling" the rectangle with an afterRender handler to get the same effect in code that is only run once.
Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53946660

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try to use css? A canvas element is just like a normal HTML element right? So you can either set it's background colour or set it's background to an image using css.

```
$('#myChart').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'); // this worked for me but I'm guessing you can set a background image using css like you normally do.
```

Comment: @Mark that's unfortunate. I'll try and find a better solution.

Comment: I found the solution on the chartjs issue tracker, but forgot to post back here. I've added an answer now that works with pngs!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this pretty simply, if you're willing to change the code in chart.js.

There's a function in chart.js called *clear*. You can find the clear function by searching for *clearRect*. The *clear* function is called every time chart.js redraws the chart, so that's where we'll set the background. Right below the line with *clearRect*, add the following lines.

```
...
chart.ctx.clearRect(0,0,chart.width,chart.height);

// Add these 3 lines
chart.ctx.rect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
chart.ctx.fillStyle="#fff"; // Put your desired background color here
chart.ctx.fill();
...
```

Comment: worked for me. I just forked nchart and did exactly this.