# ChartJS line chart calls plugin each time I hover a point

Tags: performance, chart.js

I am using ChartJS v2.9.3.

I am trying to add to the time line chart a conditional vertical background color that is displayed depending on if dataset's y-value is above a threshold.

The thread [Background colour of line charts in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144031/background-colour-of-line-charts-in-chart-js) gave me the idea to use the following plugin

```
const backgroundPlugin = {
  beforeDatasetDraw(chart, easing) {

    const ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    const chartArea = chart.chartArea;

    ctx.save();

    const colors = [
      'red',
      'green',
      'yellow',
      'blue'
    ];
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    // Set random background color to show how many times this function is called
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[randomNumber];

    console.log('refreshing background');
    chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data.forEach((data, index, all) => {
      // Check if value > threshold (here 350)
      if (
        chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[index].y > 350
      ) {
        const nextPointX =
          index === all.length - 1 ?
          chartArea.left :
          all[index + 1]._model.x;

        // Create vertical rectangle of color between current point and next point
        ctx.fillRect(
          nextPointX,
          chartArea.top,
          Math.abs(all[index]._model.x - nextPointX),
          chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top
        );
      }
    });
    ctx.restore();
  }
};
```

The problem I observed is that every time I hover on one point of the line chart, the plugin's `beforeDatasetDraw` function gets called a huge number of time.

The problem can be seen on this JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/avocado1/hgpukame/88/#

This is a problem for me because in my real case that causes a performance issue (I work with a more than 20.000 points datasets and I would like to have 5 different background colors depending on 5 different thresholds, meaning there could be 5 comparisons for each point of my dataset).

Would anyone have any clue on how to prevent hovering events to cause calls to my plugin ? (Or have any workaround to create a conditional background once and for all ?)