# ChartJS and jsPDF - why the background is black?

Tags: javascript, pdf, chart.js, jspdf

I am generating PDF file using jsPDF library. Everything is okay, but at page my chart has white background ( on PDF - black ):

Chart from my webpage:
[image]

And from PDF:
[image]

my code for generating file:

```
var newCanvas = document.querySelector('#canvasChart');
    var newCanvasImg = newCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
    var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
    doc.setFontSize(20);
    doc.text(15, 15, "Super Cool Chart");
    doc.addImage(newCanvasImg, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 280, 150 );
    doc.save('new-canvas.pdf');
```

Do you have an idea how to solve this ?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: [Chart.js: Canvas background color #2830](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2830)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save Chart JS charts as image without black background using blobs and filesaver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664722/how-to-save-chart-js-charts-as-image-without-black-background-using-blobs-and-fi)

Comment: An Article from github helped a lot! thank you

Answer (score 14):

Maybe later, but I solved using PNG image:

```
var newCanvasImg = newCanvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another alternative: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2830#issuecomment-227867969