# How to do click the HTML button as if the user is clicking

Tags: php, html, html5-canvas, chart.js

I follow this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664722/how-to-save-chart-js-charts-as-image-without-black-background-using-blobs-and-fi/43665423#43665423) to export Chart.js chart to image using download button and it works. And here is the image result:
[image]

If I click **save** button the image will download in my PC.

My Question is:

Is there any way or a script so that the image can be downloaded to the server's own folder as if there is a user who clicks to the **Save** button? For example once a day, the script will download the image by pressing the button and save the image to the server folder.

Please give me the enlightment.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided saves image using blob in saveas function. So what can you do is send the same blob to server using ajax call.
refer this link:
[How can javascript upload a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333378/how-can-javascript-upload-a-blob)

Comment: Thank you. You have enlightened me with your answer.

Comment: its great if my answer helps you.....you can upvote it,  if you find my answer useful.