# Downloaded image background is coming as black . when image is downloaded, using react chart js

Tags: reactjs

using react chartjs i m trying to download chart as a image.
this is my code:

```
 const saveAsImage = () => {
    const imageLink = document.createElement('a');
    
    imageLink.download ='img.png';
    imageLink.href =chartRef.current.toBase64Image('image/jpg', 1);
    
    imageLink.click();
  }
```

downloaded image background colour should be clear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664722/how-to-save-chart-js-charts-as-image-without-black-background-using-blobs-and-fi/53946660#53946660  Have you checked this

Answer (score 0):

You're using `toBase64Image('image/jpg', 1)` and jpg images don't have transparent backgrounds. Try with `image/png`.